Real positive functions in passive filter design

I have found the answer as A >= -3 with the help of the Hurwitz condition but the answer sheet says the answer is A<=2/3. Is there something I am missing or having a lack of knowledge?

Well, in order to answer (a) we need to consider the conditions when a funtion is considered PR. These conditions are:

Real part non-negative: \$\displaystyle\Re\left(\text{Z}\left(\text{j}\omega\right)\right)\ge0,\space\forall\space\omega\in\mathbb{R}\$;
Poles in left-half plane;
Symmetry: \$\displaystyle\text{Z}\left(\text{j}\omega\right)\$ must be symmetric about the imaginary axis, meaning \$\displaystyle\text{Z}\left(\text{j}\omega\right)=\overline{\text{Z}}\left(\text{j}\omega\right)\$.

Now, we can see:
\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
\text{Z}\left(\text{j}\omega\right)&=\frac{\displaystyle\left(\text{j}\omega\right)^2+\text{A}\text{j}\omega}{\displaystyle\left(\text{j}\omega\right)^2+3\text{j}\omega+2}\\
\\
&=\frac{\displaystyle\text{A}\omega\text{j}-\omega^2}{\displaystyle2-\omega^2+3\omega\text{j}}\\
\\
&=\frac{\displaystyle\left(\text{A}\omega\text{j}-\omega^2\right)\left(2+\omega^2-3\omega\text{j}\right)}{\displaystyle\left(2-\omega^2\right)^2+\left(3\omega\right)^2}\\
\\
&=\frac{\displaystyle\omega\left(2\text{A}+\omega^2\left(\text{A}+3\right)\right)\text{j}+\omega^2\left(3\text{A}-2-\omega^2\right)}{\displaystyle\left(2-\omega^2\right)^2+\left(3\omega\right)^2}
\end{split}\tag1
\end{equation}
Now, noticing condition 1. we see that \$\displaystyle\left(2-\omega^2\right)^2+\left(3\omega\right)^2>0,\space\forall\space\omega\in\mathbb{R}\$, so we must solve:
$$\omega^2\left(3\text{A}-2-\omega^2\right)\ge0\space\Longrightarrow\space3\text{A}-2-\omega^2\ge0\space\Longrightarrow\space\text{A}\ge\frac{\displaystyle2+\omega^2}{\displaystyle3}\tag2$$
Notice what happends when \$\displaystyle\omega=0\$.
